# question about keyhole contour for $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^\lambda}{(1+x)^2}dx$

Tags: contour-integration

> Evaluate using contour integration : $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^\lambda}{(1+x)^2}dx$$ where $-1<\lambda\neq 0<1$.

For $\boxed{-1<\lambda<0}$ case, we choose a suitable keyhole contour taking $z=0$ as branch point and positive $x$-axis as branch cut. Now for radius of outer circle tending to infinity and that of inner circle around $z=0$ tending to $0$, we have by residue theorem : $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^\lambda}{(1+x)^2}dx-e^{2i\pi\lambda}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^\lambda}{(1+x)^2}dx=2\pi i\lambda(-1)^{\lambda-1}=-2\pi i\lambda e^{i\pi\lambda} \\ \implies \int_0^\infty\frac{x^\lambda}{(1+x)^2}dx=\pi\lambda\frac{2i}{e^{i\pi\lambda}-e^{-i\pi\lambda}}=\frac{\lambda\pi}{\sin\lambda\pi}$$

That's one case finished. Now for $\boxed{0<\lambda<1}$, we can't keep the same contour as that will exclude the origin as before, whence $z=0$ is neither a pole nor there exists a residue at $z=0$. So what contour will be suitable for this case? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This seems related to [Closed form for $ \int_0^\infty {\frac{{{x^n}}}{{1 + {x^m}}}dx }$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110457/closed-form-for-int-0-infty-fracxn1-xmdx).

Comment: There is still a branch cut in the positive $x$-axis when $0<\lambda<1$ and you can use exactly the same method.

Comment: @Kemono Chen, I got that. But this contour still excludes the origin. So doesn't it make any difference?

Comment: The integral on the arc around the origin contributes nothing. It makes no difference.